# How do you complete the Wizard Dance challenge?

Tags: hero-academy

The second to last **Meet the Council** challenge involves a row of wizards against an array of Tribe units, but I cannot figure out how to take out all the units with just five action points.  Specifically, the Axe Thrower in the bottom left corner is a problem, as none of the wizard's bolts will (initially) hit him.  How do you complete this challenge?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1** - Use the Inferno on the Warrior in the bottom middle.

[image: Step 1 - Fireball]

**Step 2** - Use a scroll on the top Wizard and attack the unit directly in front of him.  This will knock out the top three units, including the middle Axe Thrower, so that the bolt from the bottom wizard can hit the bottom Axe Thrower.

[image: Step 2 - Scroll Top]

**Step 3** - Use a scroll on the bottom Wizard and attack the unit directly in front of him.

[image: Step 3 - Scroll Bottom]

**Step 4** - Victory!

[image: Step 4 - Victory]